# Preloading by jquery

Tags: jquery

I am developing a website and i am using [QueryLoader](http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader-preload-your-website-in-style/) to preload my website so that it loads all of a sudden..

I am using this following code :

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="load/css/queryLoader.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='load/js/queryLoader.js'></script>

    <script>
    QueryLoader.selectorPreload = "body";
    QueryLoader.init();
    </script>
```

But i am not getting the desired result as it first normally loads the website and then QueryLoader come into the scene.. How can i bring the QueryLoader to load first..

Comment: From the docs: `Be aware that you can only preload a single element. So using a class selector could cause some problems.` I guess you'll have to skip the selector if you want the whole document to be preloaded.

Comment: I removed
        QueryLoader.selectorPreload = "body";
Piece of code.. but still the same problem..

Comment: What exactly is the need you have? Perhaps a better script can be found and newer. 1.3 is ancient

Comment: Also I think it is supposed to be placed inline at the end of your `<body>` (i.e. not in the `<head>`)

Comment: Yup i place the whole code just before </body> tag..

Comment: @mplungjan i just want that the loader should load the images... in my case first my site loads normally and then queryloader come into scene..

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me a script to examine the DOM for img tags will have to either load the page into a jquery var OR wait for the Dom to load

If you do not want any images to load normally, you could use placeholders, put the image URL in a data attribute and simply preload them using something like

```
$(function() { 
  var img, preloadArr=[],$imgs=$("img");
  $imgs.each(function() {
    img =new Image();
    img.src=$(this).data("URL");
    preloadArr.push(img);
  });
  $imgs.each(function(i) {
     $(this).attr("src",preloadArr[i].src);
  });

});
```